# EF Code First Migrations Not Seeding Data When Deployed To Production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have an MVC 5 application set up with code first migrations. On my local machine I am able to run the following commands and the database gets updated:

```
add-migration SomeMigration
update-database
```

I have deployed my application through VS using the File System option as its being deployed to a local server. The deployment publishes successfully - no errors.

When i navigate to the site I can see tables are created using SQL Server Managment Studio, but no seed data is applied? Below is my seed class?

```
  namespace MyApp.Migrations
  {

     internal sealed class Configuration :   
     DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            MigrationsDirectory = @"Persistence\Migrations";
        }

        protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            // Seed stuff

        }

    }
}
```

How do I get it apply the seed data and when I make changes to the Models on my local machine and redeploy I get the `database context has changed. Please consider using code first migration` error?

Comment: a pragmatic and prob not best practice solution but I'd change the connection in your web config to point at your live database and run a migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see from your code that you have decided for DbMigration. Whenever you run the migration and update the database it will run the seed method.

For example it will be called:
Every time when the `Update-Database` command in Nuget is executed.

Alternatively, it can be also be called from code like that:

```
  Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration());
  ...
  ...
  dbContext.Database.Initialize(true);
```

or by using the DbMigrator:

```
 DbMigrator migrator = new DbMigrator(new Configuration());
 migrator.Update();
```

One thing you have to know it, the Seed method will be called X-times where X is the ranking/level of the database migration.

more info: https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

*!!You must to set the database initializer!!*

Comment: how can I issue the update-database command once an application is deployed to production? The update-database only works within VS whilst working on a local version?

Comment: Plus none if this is documented on the microsoft asp mvc website on thier tutorial on `http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/migrations-and-deployment-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application`?

Comment: where do I define this code `Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ApplicationDbContext, Configuration());
  ...
  ...
  dbContext.Database.Initialize(true);`

Comment: @ozzii 1)here is an example for the command line: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj618307.aspx 2)You have to put the Database.SetInitializer before any DbContext is created.

Comment: @ozzii you can just copy the tools with the file migrate.exe and installed with your project for example a directory \Migration\ and when you are installing the application you can call it from the command line with desried params

Comment: @ozzii you need always for EF a database Initializer without it you can not create the  database, I think you must have it somewhere in your code!

Comment: I've found this tutorial which explains it better incase it helps anyone else. http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/automated-migration-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: @ozzii I know this tutorial, it is really good and it will give you the whole fundamental knowledge about EF & I can also recommending you to get this book by Julia Lerman, Rowan Miller, http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022220.do

Comment: I used the first one in the constructor of the DbContext. Works ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly change your connection string to point to PROD and run your migrations or you can implement code to run migrations on deployment. In some environments that may be acceptable, but our DBAs would never allow that - they require tested scripts we give them. We have followed something similar to [this](http://cpratt.co/migrating-production-database-with-entity-framework-code-first/#at_pco=smlwn-1.0&at_si=54ad5c7b61c48943&at_ab=per-12&at_pos=0&at_tot=1) for our process.

Seeding is definitely an issue as for some reason this isn't included in scripting. We simply avoid adding any seeding in the migrations and instead use the Seed() in the database initializer. This will only run when the database is created which is perfect for lookup tables. When we need to have data added or updated after it is up and running, we use Sql() commands inside the Up() method of the migration (these get scripted).

Regarding the error "database context has changed. Please consider using code first migration" - that has nothing to do with seeding. That usually means you have not applied the migration to the deployed database. When you change your model locally, you need to update the deployed database with the migration via scripting or other methods.